# name:instagram automatic reels scrolling project status:failed

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, helper, pls

```
from selenium *import* webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by *import* By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui *import* WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support *import* expected_conditions *as* EC

chrome_options *=* webdriver.ChromeOptions()

chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-save-password-bubble")

driver *=* webdriver.Chrome(options*=*chrome_options)

driver.maximize_window()

username *=* input("Nickname:")

password *=* input("Password:")

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, "username")))

username_element *=* driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username")

password_element *=* driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")

username_element.send_keys(username)

password_element.send_keys(password)

login_element *=* driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div\[2\]/div/div/div\[2\]/div/div/div\[1\]/section/main/article/div\[2\]/div\[1\]/div\[2\]/form/div/div\[3\]")

login_element.click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div\[2\]/div/div/div\[2\]/div/div/div\[1\]/div\[1\]/div\[1\]/div/div/div/div/div\[2\]/div\[4\]/span/div/a")))

reelselement *=* driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div\[2\]/div/div/div\[2\]/div/div/div\[1\]/div\[1\]/div\[1\]/div/div/div/div/div\[2\]/div\[4\]/span/div/a")

reelselement.click()

input("Press Enter to close the browser...")

driver.quit()
```

Normally, when a reel ends, it should pass to the next reel, but it doesn't. I wrote the code, but when it didn't work, I deleted it, please help .

this failed code:

```
    while "reelViewer" in driver.page_source:
        try:
            # Aşağı ok tuşuna basarak sayfayı kaydır
            driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
            # Bir süre bekle (istediğiniz süreyi ayarlayabilirsiniz)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@data-testid='reelViewer']"))) 
        except Exception as e:
            # Reels bitip bitmediğini kontrol etmek için bir şart ekleyin
            if "reelViewer" not in str(e):
                break

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Hata oluştu: {str(e)}")

finally:
    # Tarayıcıyı kapatın
    if 'driver' in locals():
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: first format question to make code readable

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.